# Trim by length in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hi I'd like to trim curve by length but geometry nodes shows the same length for all curves. Any Idea how to fix it ?
[image]

Comment: Something wrong here. Output should be curve type, not the mesh. Maybe it shows data from another viewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something wrong here. Output should be curve type, not the mesh. Maybe it shows data from another viewer?

But even if the correct node is active, I have to point that curve length has round output socket. This means that the data is singular, and can be viewed by hovering cursor:

[image]

And also that means that it has singular data, basically the length of all splines in the geometry.

To get length per spline, you should use Spline parameter:

[image]

Comment: Works when I restarted :) Thanks for help