# Geometry Nodes : handle each spline individually

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, splines

using Geometry Nodes on a curve object, is it possible to handle each spline separately ?

For instance, I would like to compute some stuff depending on each spline's length.
But the [Curve Length Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/curve_length.html) *outputs the length of all splines added together*.

How could I use a node setup *per spline* (within the same curve object) ?

Thanks !

Comment: What about the *Spline Length* node?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim by length in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267509/trim-by-length-in-geometry-nodes)

Comment: The Spline Parameter node has a Length field that may help.

Comment: Spline length and Spline parameter nodes operate on the _complete_ spline, not its individual elements. I'm searching for the answer too :-(